# Erro ao efetuar quebra de página para impressão no Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, impressão

Tenho uma página que imprime tickets em 3 vias. Cada via do ticket está dentro de uma `div` com a classe `ticket`.

Após cada via, preciso gerar uma quebra de página. Porém, ao utilizar o `page-break-after: always;` no Google Chrome, algumas vezes (a depender do conteúdo), o Google Chrome quebra a página fora do lugar desejado, desconfigurando toda a impressão. (veja na imagem abaixo a imagem que seria a logomarca cortada).

[image: Nesse exemplo, na segunda página, a imagem (que seria a logo) sai cortada]

No Microsoft Edge funciona perfeitamente.

Para facilitar a reprodução do erro, segue abaixo o meu código HTML com CSS `inline`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>

*{font-family: arial;}
@media print {
    .ticket{ 
        page-break-after: always; 
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        position: relative;
    }
    body{
        position: relative;
        background-color:red;
    }
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="ticket">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-g-198-44-7.jpg" alt="LOGO" /><br/>
        RAZAO SOCIAL DA EMPRESA LTDA.<br/>
        Endereço: Av. QUALQUER LUGAR, NÚMERO 000. NOME DO BAIRRO.<br/>
        CNPJ: 11.111.111-1111-11<br/>
        TF: 11.111.111 FP<br/>
        Isento de ISS (lei número 1.111)<br/>
        Telefones: 0800 111 1111 <br/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(00)00000-0000<br/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(00)00000-0000<br/>
        <br/>
        <strong>Via 1</strong>
        <DIV style="border:1px solid #000; padding:10px;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;width:100%;text-align:center;">Por favor, entregue <br/>esta via ao xxxxxxx</DIV><br/>
        <DIV style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;width:100%;text-align:center;">TICKET: <span style="font-weight:bold;">00000000000000</span></DIV>
        Tipo: XYZ<br/>
        <strong>OBS: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
        <strong>Info Complementar: </strong>Etiam luctus urna nec metus scelerisque, sed laoreet magna volutpat. Sed ac lacus vitae augue vestibulum condimentum ut et arcu.<br/>
        <strong>More: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
        <strong>OBS: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
        <strong>Info Complementar: </strong>Etiam luctus urna nec metus scelerisque, sed laoreet magna volutpat. Sed ac lacus vitae augue vestibulum condimentum ut et arcu.<br/>
        <strong>More: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
    </div>

    <div class="ticket">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-g-198-44-7.jpg" alt="LOGO" /><br/>
        RAZAO SOCIAL DA EMPRESA LTDA.<br/>
        Endereço: Av. QUALQUER LUGAR, NÚMERO 000. NOME DO BAIRRO.<br/>
        CNPJ: 11.111.111-1111-11<br/>
        TF: 11.111.111 FP<br/>
        Isento de ISS (lei número 1.111)<br/>
        Telefones: 0800 111 1111 <br/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(00)00000-0000<br/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(00)00000-0000<br/>
        <br/>
        <strong>Via 2</strong>
        <DIV style="border:1px solid #000; padding:10px;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;width:100%;text-align:center;">Por favor, entregue <br/>esta via ao xxxxxxx</DIV><br/>
        <DIV style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;width:100%;text-align:center;">TICKET: <span style="font-weight:bold;">00000000000000</span></DIV>
        Tipo: XYZ<br/>
        <strong>OBS: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
        <strong>Info Complementar: </strong>Etiam luctus urna nec metus scelerisque, sed laoreet magna volutpat. Sed ac lacus vitae augue vestibulum condimentum ut et arcu.<br/>
        <strong>More: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
        <strong>OBS: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
        <strong>Info Complementar: </strong>Etiam luctus urna nec metus scelerisque, sed laoreet magna volutpat. Sed ac lacus vitae augue vestibulum condimentum ut et arcu.<br/>
        <strong>More: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
    </div>

    <div class="ticket">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-g-198-44-7.jpg" alt="LOGO" /><br/>
        RAZAO SOCIAL DA EMPRESA LTDA.<br/>
        Endereço: Av. QUALQUER LUGAR, NÚMERO 000. NOME DO BAIRRO.<br/>
        CNPJ: 11.111.111-1111-11<br/>
        TF: 11.111.111 FP<br/>
        Isento de ISS (lei número 1.111)<br/>
        Telefones: 0800 111 1111 <br/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(00)00000-0000<br/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(00)00000-0000<br/>
        <br/>
        <strong>Via 3</strong>
        <DIV style="border:1px solid #000; padding:10px;font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;width:100%;text-align:center;">Por favor, entregue <br/>esta via ao xxxxxxx</DIV><br/>
        <DIV style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;width:100%;text-align:center;">TICKET: <span style="font-weight:bold;">00000000000000</span></DIV>
        Tipo: XYZ<br/>
        <strong>OBS: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
        <strong>Info Complementar: </strong>Etiam luctus urna nec metus scelerisque, sed laoreet magna volutpat. Sed ac lacus vitae augue vestibulum condimentum ut et arcu.<br/>
        <strong>More: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
        <strong>OBS: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
        <strong>Info Complementar: </strong>Etiam luctus urna nec metus scelerisque, sed laoreet magna volutpat. Sed ac lacus vitae augue vestibulum condimentum ut et arcu.<br/>
        <strong>More: </strong>Mauris placerat euismod blandit. Donec vel nisl at odio sodales gravida.<br/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Como fazer a quebra de página ocorrer no local correto usando o Google Chrome?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, fiz uns testes aqui no seu código e consegui fazer funcionar no Chrome. Aparentemente, utilizar elementos de bloco (ex.: div) com bordas, fazem quebrar o layout do page-break. Tente o seguinte:

Troque todas os elementos `<div>` que você usa com borda pelo elemento `<p>` e retire do css-inline o `width: 100%;`

Answer (score 1):

Comparando o que você descreveu com algumas situações já apresentadas por usuários como neste [link (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258861/line-breaks-not-working-in-chrome), seguem algumas sugestões para tentar solucionar o seu problema:

1. Verifique e tente alterar a margem da imagem no interior da div;
2. Alguns usuários relataram que trabalhar com elementos de tabela ao invés de div solucionaram o problema.

Boa sorte, abraço!

Comment: Poderia editar o exemplo acima de modo que fique funcional?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz alguns ajustes no código, peço para sí que veja possivelmente o ajudará:

```css
div.page {
  page-break-after: always;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <h1>Pagina 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <h1>Pagina 2</h1>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <h1>Pagina 3</h1>
</div>
```